# Using PDFMiner (Python) with online pdf files. Encode the url?

Tags: python, pdf, urllib2, fetch, urllib

I am wishing to extract the content of pdf files available online using `PDFMiner`.

My code is based on the one available in the [documentation](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html#extend) used to extract the content of PDF files on the hard disk:

```
# Open a PDF file.
fp = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)
# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
document = PDFDocument(parser)
```

That works quite well with some small changes.

Now, I have tried `urllib2.openurl` for online PDFs but that doesn't work. I get an error  message : `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found`.

How can I get a string (or whatever) from `urllib2.openurl` so that it is the same as what the `open` function when I give it a PDF file name (versus an URL)`?

Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I finally found out a solution,

I resorted on `Request` and `StringIO` and got rid off the `open('my_file', 'rd')` command

```
from urllib2 import Request
from StringIO import StringIO

url = 'my_url'

open = urllib2.urlopen(Request(url)).read()
memoryFile = StringIO(open)

parser = PDFParser(memoryFile)
```

That way Python considers the url as a file (to say so).