# Parse online PDF file with Python and PDFMiner

Tags: python, parsing, pdf

How can I parse an online PDF file with Python?

I just need the second line of the first page. I need to do this without downloading the file and I am using Python 3.5

I have tried something like this, but it didnt work: [Using PDFMiner (Python) with online pdf files. Encode the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429193/using-pdfminer-python-with-online-pdf-files-encode-the-url)

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
import urllib.request
from io import StringIO
import io

url = 'url_with_the_pdf'

open = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

memoryFile = io.StringIO(open)

parser = PDFParser(memoryFile)
```

I get this error:

```
memoryFile = io.StringIO(open) TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, 
not bytes
```

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575064/435089

Comment: what version of python are you using? the answer changes in python3.6 which allows `loads(bytes)`.  Also I suspect you don't actually have json if you need to `.replace("'", '"')`

Comment: I am using 3.6 . So i dont need the line 
    my_json = data.decode('utf-8').replace("'", '"') ??

Comment: `If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a JSONDecodeError will be raised.` -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecodeError

The decoder is probably hitting a string value which is wrapped in single quotes because of your call to `replace` and freaking out because single quotes do not encapsulate strings in JSON.  You would do well to post document you are trying to parse so we can see it.

Comment: you can pass to the ocr,pdf change to image, and ocr can distinguish the image

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 use `io.BytesIO`, i.e.

```
memoryFile = io.BytesIO(open)
```

Details: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

> ...import the `io` module and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` for text and data respectively